# Set notification time and notify user after that time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

this is my first question. Currently i am working on a library management system where a user can issue a book for a certain time. when the time is over the system will notify the user and the admin. The notification will be showed in the notification bar. I have a hard time figuring out how to do that in laravel. I am trying to do the notification part using [laravel pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to ask actual, specific questions here on this site - simply stating that you are “having a hard time” trying to figure something out is not enough. Please also note that asking for off-site resources such as tutorials etc. is explicitly considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delay()` and set a time to notify.

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);

$user->notify((new InvoicePaid($invoice))->delay($when));
```